# Nice elevators patterns for imaginative psychology

Tags: buttons, accessibility, psychology, color-blindness

For a person that could not see, would it be nice to have different elevator buttons arranged into different patterns, not sure which ones, at all, or not?

On one hand, it would make things interesting. Elevators would remind you of different places (.?or settings), ? making it even good for the blind-person's inner state machine kick in ("I'm in this setting, I'm in that setting).

On the other hand, besides the usual usability features, having the interface the same on all elevators would, at least theoretically, allow the person to know where they were "in their mind", independent of the interface, while ease of use.

Note: in all cases, there should be nice-feeling protrusions to direct the shape of the buttons on the elevator, with braille.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your actual question is here. What are you looking for in an answer?

Comment: Why so many one-sided questions. 82345261

Comment: Your questions here are all very broad and vague. I suggest you look over the [tour] to see a bit more about how this site works. Remember: questions should be based on **actual problems that you have faced** so that we can solve them. It's not a discussion site, we're here to answer specific questions about User Experience.

Comment: In the United States, elevator button layout is regulated by [accessibility standards.](http://www.access-board.gov/guidelines-and-standards/buildings-and-sites/about-the-ada-standards/guide-to-the-ada-standards/chapter-4-elevators-and-platform-lifts?highlight=WyJlbGV2YXRvciJd)

Comment: I guess I won't be seeing elevator buttons which look cool and also work intetestingly with the blind anywhere then. Forgive my dumb question.

Comment: Here in Iyaly, the elevator out of my home only has one outer button (no up/down calling buttons). The elevator will only stop while on its way while going down (if stopped it will go directly to where the usrr pressed the button irrelevantly of whether the calling floor was up or down from it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you should ask blind people what the prefer. I'm not blind so I cannot judge what a blind person would like about elevator buttons.

My current best bet is to stay persistent and keep the same button layouts for every stage

Comment: Sorry I don't really see this a good answer. Blind people are people too it is fairly easy to judge what a blind person would like, that is actually a big part of UX design (accessibility). The second part of your answer I like (and I believe is the correct answer) but you don't state why persistence/consistency is better such as avoiding confusion, quicker learning of the interface, longer memory of how to use the interface, cheaper implementation, etc.

Answer (score 1):

No. Blind people aren't stupid, they're perfectly aware of where they are. Swapping buttons and using different layouts only creates usability problems.

Imagine working with a qwerty keyboard at home and having a dvorak model at work. Does that sound handy?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose the usability problems are CREATED in this manner. It's not that they were there in the first place.

Comment: If voice recognition (here we are talking about using it for typing) is not available, and spelling is a problem, then using voice to say a language-layout'-code would help to make the keyboard work as desired (assuming compatiblre layouts), and the uuser could choose qeerty or dvorac by voice and switch as needed.